# jstree not properly initialized when used with sinon.js

Tags: jquery, jstree, qunit, sinon

I am writing a function test using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) / [qunit](http://api.qunitjs.com/).  The page I writing the test for works fine, but I am having problems getting a jstree object to load its initial data when faking the server responses with sinon in the test.

To make sure that the page I am testing and the test I am writing are using the same response data, I created a javascript object fixture called `change_dialog_fixture` that I load in place of the data returned from the server.  You can see this in the call to [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), below:

```
    $.getJSON(axes_url, function(data) {
        //ANALYSIS_PAPER.change_data = data;
        ANALYSIS_PAPER.change_data = change_dialog_fixture;
        hide_throbber(); // sinon confirms this is called
        create_change_dialog();
        console.log(ANALYSIS_PAPER.change_data); // prints
    });
```

By stepping through the code I can see that for both pages (working page and test page) the DOM element being manipulated into a jstree object (by the `create_change_dialog` function) does not have its data loaded until *after* `getJSON` returns.

After `getJSON` returns, the working page "focuses" the created tree and loads the JSON data given in `ANALYSIS_PAPER.change_data` to create the jstree structure.  On the qunit test page this doesn't happen.  The DOM element is still a jstree object, but the element is completely empty.

As the comments in the included code indicate, `hide_throbber` is called (I'm testing this using [sinon spies](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies-api)) and the `console.log` statement is printed.  No exceptions are raised and no error are indicated.  The failure is completely silent.

I thought this may be related to timing somehow, so I made my qunit test a [`asyncTest`](http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/) and added `start();` to the callback function passed to `getJSON` but this didn't change anything.  I also took a different approach and edited the [`fakeServer`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server) with `server.autoRespond = true`, but this didn't fix the problem either.

Any suggestions on further tests to run or ideas about what may be causing this are very welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that since jstree is animated the tree is really loaded asynchronously.  Because animations use `window.setTimeout` at their core and sinon can fake this function using its [`fake timers`](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock), adding a few `click.tick` statements fixed the problem.  For example:

```
$loadTreeButton.trigger("click");
this.clock.tick(1000);
equal(partOfTheTree.length, 1, "Component 1 loaded");
```

The `loaded.jstree` function listed on [jstree's core documentation page](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core) is what got me moving in the right direction by hinting that jstree was loading asynchronously.